# Problem with creating Lists for Standard Task Object

Tags: standard-objects, list-view, custom, list

"List controllers are not supported for Task"

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now. If I want to create and display a Task list (atm i'm trying to do it with a table, which already works with a custom object) what's a possible workaround in my apex class to achieve this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons `StandardSetController` and `Task` don't work together. So you have to write your own custom controller instead:

```
public with sharing class MyTaskController {

    public Task[] tasks {get; private set}

    public MyTaskController() {
        // You can extract parameters from the page URL like this...
        Id id = (Id) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        // ... and they can be used to make the query more selective
        tasks = [select Subject, Status, ... from Task where ... order by ... limit 1000];
    }
}
```

and reference that and its `tasks` field in your page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyTaskController">
    ....
</apex:page>
```

The controller will get more complicated if you need features like pagination.

Comment: That's the problem, in my case it needs t ohave pagination... I've understood what you did there (retrieve the id from the url and fetch it in a query) but what i need is to do the same thing except I'm needing to store it in a List to visualize in Visualforce. 

Is it not possible at all to store a List of Tasks?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: `Task[] tasks` is identical to `List<Task> tasks` so you can show the results in e.g. an apex:pageBlockTable. I suggest you start without the pagination and get it working; Google about pagination and you should find some sample code (and perhaps code ealing with Task).